# What makes these nested loop O(n^3)?

Tags: time-complexity

So I've been looking at these nested for loops:

```
for i = 1 to n:
    for j = i to n:
        for k = i to n:
            sum = i + j + k
```

Now I can kinda see that this is O(n^3) since it's three linearly growing, nested loops dependent on n, but I don't know how I would show this mathematically.

Comment: Read this: https://brilliant.org/wiki/big-o-notation/

Comment: That code is about the simplest example of O(n^3). Consider this, the outer loop runs n times, then on each run the second loop runs n times, so those combined run n * n times, and then the third level runs n times for each of those, so n * n * n.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Not quite - both of the inner loops run for `n - i + 1` times, although this doesn't change the complexity

Comment: @meowgoesthedog You're right, I hadn't looked to closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to calculate the exact running time (i.e. the number of iterations), Big-Oh complexity then comes naturally. Let's try to count for first few values:

`i = 1` -> `j` goes from `1` to `n`, `k` goes from `1` to `n` -> `n*n` iterations

`i = 2` -> `j` goes from `2` to `n`, `k` goes from `2` to `n` -> `(n-1)*(n-1)` iterations

`i = 3` -> `j` goes from `3` to `n`, `k` goes from `3` to `n` -> `(n-2)*(n-2)` iterations

...

`i = m` -> `j` goes from `m` to `n`, `k` goes from `m` to `n` -> `(n-m+1)*(n-m+1)` iterations

To get a total number of iterations, we obviously have to take a sum of `(n-i+1)*(n-i+1)` where `i` goes from `1` to `n`. The calculation is not that hard:

[image]

Here we used formulas for sum of first `n` natural numbers and first `n` squares. Now it is obvious that `n^3` dominates, so the time complexity is `O(n^3)`.

Comment: did you mean `(n - m + 1) * (n - m + 1)` iterations?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Off-by-one, the most common mistake in a history of mankind :) Corrected, thanks.

Comment: Yeah I had a big brain fart here, shortly after posting this it all clicked and this was precisely the answer I got. Thanks!!!!